# Docker Stack Deploy doesn't resolve environment variables with default value like Docker Compose does

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have the following example files

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: webapp:${VARIABLE_A:-${VARIABLE_B}}
```

`env.conf`

```
VARIABLE_B=123
```

`VARIABLE_A` is not set on purpose so it should fall back to `VARIABLE_B`

Docker compose is able to resolve the default value of the environment variable, however `docker stack deploy` is unable to do the same resolution

```shell
user@laptop:~$ docker compose --env-file ./env.conf convert

name: dockercomposetest
services:
  web:
    image: webapp:123
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: dockercomposetest_default
```

```shell
user@laptop:~$ env $(cat ./env.conf | xargs) docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stack

Creating service stack_web
failed to create service stack_web: 
  Error response from daemon: 
  rpc error: 
    code = InvalidArgument desc = ContainerSpec: "webapp:${VARIABLE_B}" is not a valid repository/tag
```

As you can see when using `docker stack deploy` it detects `${VARIABLE_A:-${VARIABLE_B}}` is an environment variable that, because `VARIABLE_A` is not set, it should default to `${VARIABLE_B}` however it does not resolve its value which is `123`

Obviously, webapp does not exist, it's only an example, but the above error output should be this instead

```shell
user@laptop:~$ env $(cat ./env.conf | xargs) docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stack

Creating service stack_web
failed to create service stack_web: 
  Error response from daemon: 
  rpc error: 
    code = InvalidArgument desc = ContainerSpec: "webapp:123" is not a valid repository/tag
```

Why does this happen? Is there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference see in moby [docker stack deploy in 1.13 doesn't load .env file as docker-compose up does](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133). Specifically [Comment from kinghuang](https://%20https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133#issuecomment-852350362)

"I have my developers use docker-compose config to pre-process Docker Compose projects before passing them to docker stack deploy. You can do this in one line with:

```
docker stack deploy -c <(docker-compose config) stack-name-here
```

That way, all Docker Compose features including .env processing are fully applied."

Comment: I haven't tested this solution, but I'll mark it as valid since it looks way cleaner than what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

The workaround i ended up doing for `docker stack deploy` is using `envsubst` to replace env vars

`user@laptop:~$ env $(cat ./env.conf | xargs) envsubst < ./docker-compose.yml | docker stack deploy --compose-file - stack`

Documentation says that by using `--compose-file -` it takes the `stdin` as the docker compose file, so basically what this does is to first resolve all the variables in the `docker-compose.yml` then pass the result using a pipe to `docker stack deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another nice way how you can overcome this problem.
You have to create a ".env" file with all the variables you want to add to the environment for example: `APP_NAME=Example` . Then in your stack-compose.yml you can declare it like this:

```
version: "3.9" 
services: 
  myservice: 
    env_file: 
      - .env
```

After this, you should run the following command:

```
docker stack config -c stack-compose.yml | docker stack deploy -c - mystackname
```

Which will insert the variables that you declared in the .env file in the stack_compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    environment:
      APP_NAME: "Example"
```

In this link [How to pass env variables in docker swarm stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76651942/9534127)

You will find a very good explanation of how to do this. I had the same problem and overcame it this way.
Regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574540)

Comment: Hey @DaveM thanks for your comment. I improved my answer based on the link explanation. Regards